# Style for shapes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, selector, shapes

I use shapes to give my views (buttons) a rounded corner and a gradient. To switch between pressed, enabled and disabled I use a selector. Every item in the selector is a shape with an other gradient. Now I want to have all my shapes to have some default styles like all should have the same corner radius.

Selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_button_disabled"
      android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_button_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_button_enabled" /></selector>
```

Shapes:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/yellow_50"
        android:endColor="@color/yellow_25"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <corners android:radius="5px"/>
```

How can I define the corner radius at only one spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your 5px as a dimension resource (dimens.xml)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Then you can access it from all your drawable shape files.

```
<dimen name="radius">5px</dimen>
```

And access it as:

```
"@dimen/radius"
```